# Java- Fake MouseEvents without focusing window

Tags: java, events, applet, mouse

I have an applet loaded into a JFrame which I can send mouse information to like so:

```
MouseEvent m;

    m = new MouseEvent(owner.loader.applet.getComponent(0),
            MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,
            System.currentTimeMillis(),
            button,
            x,
            y,
            0,
            false);

            owner.loader.applet.getComponent(0).dispatchEvent(m);
```

Now, when I send this mouse event to the applet, my JFrame will come into focus. How can I stop it from doing this? When I send a mousemove event instead of a mousepress, it doesn't take focus.

I'm using the BUTTON1_MASK event for the button parameter.

Comment: Mousepress is simulating an actual mousepress, just like if you clicked it yourself the frame would become focused. I don't know much about java's mouse events but in botting programs used for games, when someone wants to send a mouse click without being focused on the screen, usually memory editing is involved.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I've got it, the first argument of MouseEvent was supposed to be applet, and the others had to be applet.getComponent(0). I'll leave this here just incase anyone else has my problem.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Could you please update it with code or/and explanations.